# Chrome Extension Development : Message passing Problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Having a problem while passing messages using content scripts in Google chrome extension dev
My Code structure looks like this:

popup.html:

```
var oList;
function getHTML()
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
     chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action:"getHTML"}, function handler(response) {
      oList = response.dom;
     });
   });

   alert("oList = "+oList );
}
```

and my content Script looks like this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(request.action == "getHTML"){
   sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("HTML").length});   
     }
  });
```

When I debug my code by putting a breakpoint at "`oList = response.dom;`" in my popup.html, i get the 
right value set from the content script. But while executing the extension, the "`alert("oList = "+oList );`" code
from the popup.html seems to be executing first before it goes to the server.. And therefore, its value is
not being set.. Can somebody tell me if I am wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Its behaving really weird.. If I do an "Inspect Popup" without breakpoints, its working.. If I just plainly execute, it just doesn't run ! I added console.logs() inside the response and see that its just not executing. But when I debug, the code is going in.. I am able to see the logs in the console and m also able to get the alerts. Why is this happ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Chrome API methods are asynchronous. It means that when you are calling them the script doesn't wait for their response and simply continues executing. If you want to execute something on response you should put it inside callback function:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action:"getHTML"}, function handler(response) {
  oList = response.dom;
  alert("oList = "+oList );
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.. But thats what I am doing right ? My 'sendRequest' has the code 'oList = response.dom;' which should set the value to oList. This is getting set while debugging it, but not while executing it :(

Comment: I add a console.log("oList = "+oList);. But I see the result in the console only when I debug.. Not when I execute :(

Comment: @paypalcomp That's not what you are doing. Your assignment doesn't happen before display. Imagine that you have very big amount of data to transfer and it would take 1 hour. Your code would execute in such order: `var oList;` immediately followed by `alert(oList);` (it doesn't wait for data to load), then 1 hour later: `oList = response.dom;`. Now your amount of data is smaller so it takes only few milliseconds for callback to get triggered, but it still happens few milliseconds later than your alert.